# Error jQuery each

Tags: jquery

Quiero obtener el contenido de unas las etiquetas

con class=".parrafo_editable", pero me sale error y no sé que puedo estar haciendo mal.

```
$(".panel-ficha .parrafo_editable").each(function(indice, elemento){
    elemento.text();//Acá supuestamente es el error
});
```

Aquí el código completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contenedor-panel").on("click", ".panel-ficha", function() {
      var t = $(this); //t es panel-ficha
      var tp = t.next(); //tp es panel-aspecto
      var p = t
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .find(".panel-aspecto");
      tp.slideToggle();
      p.slideUp();
    });
  
    $(".contenedor-panel").on("click", ".panel-aspecto-descripcion", function() {
      var t = $(this);
      var tp = t.next();
      var p = t
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .find(".panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores");
      tp.slideToggle();
      p.slideUp();
    });
  
    $(".editar").on("click", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  
    let panelAspectoDescripcionIndicadores =
      '<div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas">' +
      '<div class="puntaje">' +
      '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div>' +
      '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div>' +
      '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div>' +
      '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div>' +
      '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div>' +
      "</div>" +
      '<div class="observacion">' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div>' +
      '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div>' +
      "</div>" +
      '<div class="pregunta">' +
      '<form class="pregunta-contenedor">' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial" contentEditable="true">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">' +
      '<select class="comboBox" disabled>' +
      '<option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>' +
      '<option value="Alta">Alta</option>' +
      '<option value="Media">Media</option>' +
      '<option value="Baja">Baja</option>' +
      "</select>" +
      "</div>" +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text" disabled></div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i" disabled></div>' +
      '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">' +
      '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">' +
      '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">' +
      "</div>" +
      "</form>" +
      "</div>" +
      '<input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA">' +
      "</div>";
  
    $(".btn-crearElemento").on("click", function() {
      $(".panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores").html(
        panelAspectoDescripcionIndicadores
      );
    });
  
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-categoria", function() {
      let actual = $(this);
      let btn_categoria_actual = actual.prev();
      $(btn_categoria_actual).html(panelAspectoDescripcionIndicadores);
    });
  
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-pregunta", function() {
      let actual = $(this);
      actual
        .prev()
        .append(
          '<form class="pregunta-contenedor">' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial" contentEditable="true">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">' +
            '<select class="comboBox" disabled>' +
            '<option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>' +
            '<option value="Alta">Alta</option>' +
            '<option value="Media">Media</option>' +
            '<option value="Baja">Baja</option>' +
            "</select>" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton" disabled></div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text" disabled></div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i" disabled></div>' +
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">' +
            '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">' +
            '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">' +
            "</div>" +
            "</form>"
        );
    });
  
    $(document).on("click", ".editarPregunta", function() {
      $(this)
        .parents(".pregunta-contenedor")
        .children(".pregunta-preguntaInicial")
        .attr("contentEditable", "true")
        .focus();
    });
  
    $(document).on("click", ".eliminarPregunta", function() {
      let actual = $(this)
        .parent()
        .parent();
      actual.remove();
    });
  
    $(document).on("paste", ".pregunta-preguntaInicial", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
      document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
    });
  
    $(document).on("paste", ".panel-ficha", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
      document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
    });

    $(document).on("paste", ".panel-aspecto-descripcion", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
      document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
    });

    //TODO:
    $(document).on("paste", ".parrafo_editable", function(e){
      var texto = $(this).text() + event.clipboardData.getData('text/PLAIN');
        if(texto.length > 30){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("No puede escribir más de 30 caracteres");
            return false;
        }
    });

  });
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .panel-aspecto-descripcion {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }

    .panel-ficha {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }

    .parrafo_editable {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .btn-crearElemento {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        /* margin-top: 10px; */
    }

    .btn-categoria {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-guardar {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        background-color: #00a65a;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: 1px solid #008d4c;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .comboBox:hover{
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    .text:hover{
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    .subirArchivo:hover{
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /*CONTENEDOR*/
  .contenedorTotalPreguntas {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  /*PUNTAJE*/
  .puntaje {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    background: #3c8dbc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .puntaje-descripcion {
    width: 41%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /*OBSERVACIONES*/
  .observacion {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ecf0f5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .observacion-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionInicial {
    width: 33%;
  }
  
  .observacion-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionFinal {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  .observacion-i {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .observacion-malo {
    background-color: #fb86af;
  }
  
  .observacion-regular {
    background: #fbd386;
  }
  
  .observacion-bueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-muyBueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-acciones {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  /*PREGUNTA*/
  .pregunta {
    /* font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
        height: 55px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center; */
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-contenedor {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    /* height: 49px; */
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 49px;
  }
  
  .pregunta-preguntaInicial {
    /* display: flex; */
    display: block;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    /* justify-content: flex-start; */
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-align: justify;
}
  
  .pregunta-comboBox {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  select {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  option {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-radioButton {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  input[type="radio"] {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-text {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .text {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .pregunta-subirArchivo {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-iconos {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  /**/
  .pregunta-iconos img {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  /**/
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
  
  .btn-pregunta {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
  
  
  .contenedor-panel{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.panel-ficha{
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
}

.panel-aspecto{
    display: none;
}

.panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores{
    display: none;
}

/*------------------------------------*/

.panel-aspecto-descripcion{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #D7CCC8;
    border: 1px solid #A1887F;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #BCAAA4;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/

.panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores-descripcion{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #FFFDE7;
    border: 1px solid #FFF9C4;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #BCAAA4;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/

.estilos-ficha-supervision{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha">
  <p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> 
  <div class="contenedor_icon">
    <img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> 
    <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha">
  <p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p>
  <div class="contenedor_icon">
    <img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png">
    <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué se supone que quieres hacer con esa línea: `elemento.text();`? ¿Obtener el valor del elemento? ¿cambiar el valor del elemento? Así es un sin sentido realmente.

Comment: El código que has puesto no funciona porque falta la función `cambiar_nombre`

Comment: No no, solo quiero obtener el contenido de las etiquetas <p class="parrafo_editable">

Comment: Por eso no sé como puedo hacer para el contenido, pense que con .text() se resolveria el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No funciona porque `element` como lo usas dentro del bucle no es reconocido como una variable de jQuery.

Puedes usar `$(this)`:

```js
$(".panel-ficha .parrafo_editable").each(function(indice){
    console.log($(this).text());//Acá supuestamente es el error
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> <div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha"><p id="a" class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> <div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div>
```

---

O puedes seguir usando `element`, pero con un método de obtención de Javascript puro, como puede ser `textContent`:

```js
$(".panel-ficha .parrafo_editable").each(function(indice,element){
    console.log(element.textContent);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> <div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha"><p id="a" class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> <div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div>
```

Comment: a yaaaaaa, que interesante!!!! Tendré que tener más cuidado con Jquery. Como use mi lógica no pensaba que iba a fallar, pero al final era Jquery. Gracias @A.Cedano.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal jQuery es curioso con eso. En algunos casos cuando quieres crear referencias a elementos, si no le pones la `$` delante luego no puedes usar métodos propios de jQuery con ese elemento. Para casos como `each` siempre es  mejor usar `$(this)` en el contexto de jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tu evento de la siguiente forma:

```
$(".panel-ficha .parrafo_editable").each(function(){
    $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi tambien:
pasando el elemento a `jquery` con $(elemento)!

```js
$(".panel-ficha .parrafo_editable").each(function(indice,elemento){
    console.log($(elemento).text()); //Acá supuestamente es el error
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> <div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div>

<div contenteditable="false" class="panel-ficha"><p id="a" class="parrafo_editable" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha</p> <div class="contenedor_icon"><img class="cambiar_nombre" onclick="cambiar_nombre(this);" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png"> <img onclick="eliminar_elemento(this);" class="img-panel-aspecto-descripcion" title="eliminar" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png"></div></div>
```